# How should I approach a codebase in foreign language?

Tags: visual-studio, legacy-code

I have a codebase with parts written in foreign language. Code is still maintained and developed by developers who use this language. I'm trying to find the best solution to work with the code effectively, but I'm not sure what should I do.

I've found a nice [Visual Studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f2321406-c5bb-42b7-9660-dfacd313eeed) for translating source code on fly.

But even if this is nice tool and helpes much, a developer still must select text, press button and wait for a translation.

What is the best approach to this problem? Should I push to translate the whole codebase?

Answer (score 1):

I've been in a similar situation. Your choice depends on the team and where the code is heading.

The team: do all members speak the same language (doesn't have to be their native language)? I'd say this is a prerequisite; there must be at least one language that they all speak (and read and write).

The code's future: more and more we are working in international contexts. So if the code is written in French now, but the company has been acquired by a US company, it may be interesting to look at writing future code in English.

Whatever you do, consult the entire team and choose one language. Consistency is key. Working with two languages in a single codebase increases confusion and there are often enough other reasons that code is confusing (I mainly work on and specialize in legacy projects, so I may be biased :) If you have classes called `Customer` and `CustomerAddress` somewhere, but then also an `AchatDeClient` (CustomerPurchase in French), things will get confusing and difficult to find quickly.

Making the transition is difficult of course. You will have to make a plan and a concentrated effort that is limited in time to translate all the code.

The translation tool you mention seems useful, but only during the transition. It doesn't seem handy to work with in the long term.